# Why isn't Integrated Windows Authentication working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I created a new **ASP.NET MVC application** with the **Web API template**. I selected the authentication mode as "**Windows Authentication**" while creating the project.

I added **windows authentication** in the **web.config**:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>
```

I made sure that **Windows Authentication** was installed on **IIS** and **enabled** in the same web application in IIS.

I created a controller action that displays the user's username:

```
public JsonResult Login()
{
    string userName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    string message = String.Format("Welcome, {0}!", userName);
    return Json(userName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When I access this URL in the browser, the user is not prompted for the credentials and the returned value is an empty string.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you deactivate basic auth and activate windows auth in IIS for this site?

Comment: @[Dirk Trilsbeek] Ah, you got it. I forgot to disable anonymous authentication. It's working now. Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to deactivate `Anonymous Authentication` and activate `Windows Authentication` for your site in the IIS management console.